# How to connect Robomongo to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am have MongoDB and Robomongo in my running system, and I am using Robomongo as the client.

I have installed MongoDB on a different system which I am treating as server, and I want to connect Robomongo of my system (as a client) to MongoDB on another system (server). What steps should I follow to achieve the same?

I am using the machine name, as the system's IP address is not static. But even if I use the system's IP address, I get the same error:

> connect failed, can't connect couldn't connect to server W7IN05200067D:27017"

I am connecting to it directly, and I am not using any authentication.

Answer (score 60):

I was able to connect Robomongo to a remote instance of MongoDB running on Mongo Labs using the connection string as follows:

1. **Download** the latest version of Robomongo. I downloaded 0.9 RC6 from [here](https://robomongo.org/download).
2. From the connection string, **populate the server address and port numbers** as follows.

   [image: Connection settings]
3. **Populate DB name and username and password** as follows under the authentication tab.

   [image: Authentication settings]
4. **Test** the connection.

   [image: Test connection]

   [image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the great explanation

Answer (score 20):

Note: Commenting out bind_ip can make your system vulnerable to security flaws. Please see *[Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/#limit-network-exposure)*. It is a better idea to add more IP addresses than to open up your system to everything.

You need to edit your */etc/mongod.conf* file's *bind_ip* variable to include the IP of the computer you're using, or eliminate it altogether.

I was able to connect using the following *mongod.conf* file. I commented out *bind_ip* and uncommented *port*.

```
# mongod.conf

# Where to store the data.

# Note: if you run MongoDB as a non-root user (recommended) you may
# need to create and set permissions for this directory manually.
# E.g., if the parent directory isn't mutable by the MongoDB user.

dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

# Where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

logappend=true

port = 27017

# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all
interfaces.

#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1


# Disables write-ahead journaling
# nojournal = true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true

#auth = true

# Verbose logging output.
#verbose = true

# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers)
#objcheck = true

# Enable db quota management
#quota = true

# Set oplogging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#diaglog = 0

# Ignore query hints
#nohints = true

# Enable the HTTP interface (Defaults to port 28017).
#httpinterface = true

# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality
#noscripting = true

# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
#notablescan = true

# Disable data file preallocation.
#noprealloc = true

# Specify .ns file size for new databases.
# nssize = <size>

# Replication Options
# In replicated MongoDB databases, specify the replica set name here
#replSet=setname

# Maximum size in megabytes for replication operation log
#oplogSize=1024

# Path to a key file storing authentication info for connections
# between replica set members
#keyFile=/path/to/keyfile
```

Don't forget to restart the *mongod* service before trying to connect:

```
service mongod restart
```

From Robomongo, I used the following connection settings:

**Connection Tab:**

- Address: [VPS IP] : 27017

**SSH Tab:**

- SSH Address: [VPS IP] : 22
- SSH User Name: [Username for sudo enabled user]
- SSH Auth Method: Password
- User Password: Supersecret

Comment: I don't have `etc` folder and `mongod.conf` in my Mongo folder. Do you know, was Mongo installed wrong on my machine or should it be added somehow?

Comment: @YuriDorokhov sorry for the delayed response, /etc folder is in the root directory of your Linux installation not in the your Mongo folder.

Comment: Do not EVER comment out `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1`!!!!! You can add other IPs to it, but if you comment out bind_ip you are creating a potential security vulnerability allowing public access to your mongodb server. @ShahNewazKhan Please modify your post. See mongodb security checklist here
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/#limit-network-exposure

Comment: @linxtion thanks for the heads up, I have updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 6):

1. First you have to run the `mongod` command in your terminal. Make sure the command executes properly.
2. Then in a new terminal tab run the `mongo` command.
3. Then open the Robomongo GUI and create a new connection with the default settings.

Comment: I have been having this issue and looking for answers for hours... This literally solved my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Robomongo does not yet work with MongoDB 3:

*[Can't Connect to Mongo 3.0 DB server #771](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/771)*

Comment: What is the alternative then ?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Robomongo 0.8.x doesn't work with MongoDB 3.0:

- *[MongoDB and Robomongo: Can't connect (authentication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29325011/mongodb-robomongo-cant-connect-authentication/32945088#32945088)*
- *[Add support for SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication (MongoDB 3.0+) #766](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/766)*

For now, don't use Robomongo. For me, the best solution is to use [MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what we do:

- Create a new connection, set the name, IP address and the appropriate port:

  [image: Connection setup]
- Set up authentication, if required

  [image: Authentication settings]
- Optionally set up other available settings for SSL, SSH, etc.
- Save and connect

Comment: Narrow down the situation by using the IP for now.  

What port the remote mongod server is using? Is this the default 27017?  Is the problem specific to robomongo?! Can you connect using `mongo` shell? You might need to change SSL/SSH settings.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no authentication enabled (username/password) and still unable to connect. Just use localhost and default port. Click Test and Save, if test connection is successful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Regards
Jagdish

Comment: I would like keep my original answer and without any edits and with Typos....

Answer (score 0):

Robomongo 0.8.5 definitely works with MongoDB 3.X (mine version of MongoDB is 3.0.7, the newest one).

The following steps should be done to connect to the MongoDB server:

1. Install MongoDB server (on Windows, Linux, etc. Your choice)
2. Run the MongoDB server. Don't set *net.bind_ip = 127.0.0.1* if you want the client to connect to the server by server's own IP address!
3. Connect to the server from Robomongo with the server IP address + set authentication if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I exported the following connection from Studio 3T:

> mongodb://youn-nosql-grej-test:xxxyyyzzz@youn-nosql-grej-test.documents.azure.com:10255/admin?3t.uriVersion=2&3t.certificatePreference=RootCACert:accept_any&3t.databases=admin&3t.connectionMode=direct&3t.useClientCertPassword=false&3t.connection.name=Grej-Test&readPreference=primary&ssl=true

And I filled it in in the following screens:

[image: Connection]

[image: Authentication]

[image: SSL]

[image: OK!]

Answer (score -2):

1. Comment out the */etc/mongod.conf* file's *bind_ip*
2. Download https://download.robomongo.org/0.9.0-rc9/windows/robomongo-0.9.0-rc9-windows-x86_64-0bb5668.exe
3. Connection tab:

   3.1 Name (whatever)

   3.2 Address (IP address of the server) : Port number (27017)
4. SSH tab (I used my normal [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) connection details)

   4.1 SSH Address:  (IP address of server)

   4.2 SSH User Name (User Name)

   4.3 User Password (password)