# Accessing MongoDB from Windows & Mac Client Machines

Tags: linux, windows, macos, mongodb, redhat

I have MongoDB 3.2 installed on my Linux Red Hat server.

I am starting to access it and looking at the mongo Shell instructions.

For a Windows machine, the instructions want me to get to the command prompt and change dirs to the installation directory. The problem is, MongoDB is installed on my web server and not my local windows machine.

Question: does Mongo Shell apply to me then? How do I start using, connecting and accessing Mongo from my Windows and Mac machines?

[Note: I am a traditional MySQL / phpMyAdmin developer looking to advance to MongoDB]

**Amendments:**

(1) With the help of @AlexBlex I am progressing to trying to connect to my MongoDB on my server from Robomongo on my windows client. I get the following error when trying to setup my connection. I tried the address with just my server ip and with http://{my server ip}. Neither worked. See screen shot of error
[image]

(2) This is what I have in my current `mongod.conf` file:

```
#port=27017
bind_ip=127.0.0.1
```

(3) here is what my connection settings look like. Oddly, @AlexBlex's solution below shows an SSH tab on his Mac version. The Windows and Mac versions I just installed lacks that tab.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. @ShahNewasKhan is brilliant. See [How to connect Robomongo to MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336163/how-to-connect-robomongo-to-mongodb)

All you need to do is SSH to server and edit `mongod.conf` file:

1. uncomment `#port=27017` to `port=27017`
2. comment `bind_ip=127.0.0.1` to `#bind_ip=127.0.0.1`
3. restart mongodb via `service mongod restart`

Then create a mongo connection via your server ip in the address field and 27017 in the port field

Hope this helps mongo newbies and start-ups like me :) Good luck.

Now I just need to figure out how to make this secure. My concern is that anyone who knows my server ip can hack into my MongoDB

Comment: That's great you have found a solution on SO. Please accept your answer to mark the question as resolved. It would be great if you add a note to the answer, that this setup opens access to your database to anyone in the Internet and should not be used in production unless you enable mongodb auth and ssl: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-checklist/

Answer (score 1):

If you install MongoDB on your local machine, you can use the `Mongo` shell like below to connect to your remote server

```
mongo  yourserver:27017/database
```

You will  have to configure your Mongo server to allow remote connections. In order to achieve this you need to have the following line in your `/etc/mongodb.conf` file. You need to replace `10.0.0.2` with the ip address of  your client machine.

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1,10.0.0.2
```

Comment: Thank you @Jaco. MongoDB is not installed on my local machine. It is installed on my Linux Red Hat server. I am trying my best to get started and learn MongoDB. So how do I "configure [my] Mongo server to allow remote connections" ?

Comment: You still need to install it locally to call `mongo  yourserver:27017/database` =)

Comment: Really. So how does it work as a web-based app service tool? Do all users out there need to have MongoDB installed on their computers in order to use my web app?

Comment: Your users do not connect to mongodb. They connect to http server, which runs your application, which connects to the db. To be able to connect to the db, you need a client installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need either `ssh` to the server where mongodb is installed, or install mongodb on local machine.

For robomongo to connect to remote host you need to ssh to the server, and check it listens on external interface:

```
lsof -i | grep 27017
```

In case it is bound to localhost only, you need to edit a line with [bind_ip](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) in `/etc/mongodb.conf` and restart the service.

I would recommend to keep it listening on the local interface only for security reasons, and use ssh tunnelling to connect:

[image]

Comment: Ok @AlexBlex. I am getting it -- the clouds are starting to lift :) So unlike MySQL with the Web Interface of phpMyAdmin, I need to do all of my MongoDB work from the command-line?

Comment: There are some GUI https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/ I like Compass and robomongo, but basically yes, I don't think you can completely avoid command line.

Comment: Ok. I did install Robomongo on my Mac last night. But then I came up against the mac window of needing to setup my connection. That's where I got lost. What to do next?

Comment: If I install Robomongo on my local machines and connect from there, do I need to make the `bind_id` change for localhost as recommended by @Jaco above?

Comment: I did your SSH command and got the following `mongod    10980   mongod    8u  IPv4 355046325      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:27017 (LISTEN)` -- so am I good to go?

Comment: I have updated the answer. bind_ip works similar to how it works in mysql. It is recommended to bind to localhost for security reasons, but it will make it impossible to connect to the database from external web.

Comment: Ok, so it listens to local interface only. I have added a screenshot how to connect robomongo to mongodb via ssh.

Comment: I got an error when trying to setup my connection. I tried the address with just my server ip and with http://{my server ip}. Neither worked. See screen shot of error at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bytqhoir_Tt5N2RFTldTamdVaFU

Comment: This is what I have in my current mongod.conf file: `#port=27017` and `bind_ip=127.0.0.1`

Comment: @H.Ferrence, please add the error you have to the question to make it useful for other people who may face the same issue.

Comment: Can't say the error image is terribly informative. Please read basics about how tunnelling works https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol. Robomongo does exactly exactly that in the background. I have added some annotations to the images with sincere hope it helps.

Comment: I posted another amendment to my OQ

Comment: How did you get the SSH tab on your client machine @AlexBlex?

Comment: Maybe Robomongo is not the right tool. It looks like it might go away due to lack of financial resources. I am looking for other more reliable and working client UI software.