# Filter data for user access with Meteor.publish

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

I need help: I'm not able to make (Meteor.publish) work to filter data of a page and to apply permits added by users (owner).

Now I show you the code that I've written in Coffescript (publish.coffee and the JS for DataTable using the package (aldeed:tabular - https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/tabular)

> 1. publish.coffee

```
Meteor.publish 'reportPage', ->
     userId = @userId
       reportpage = Dealers.find('owner': userId)
     if Dealers
       return reportPage
  @ready()
```

> 2. reportpage.js

```
TabularTables ={};

Meteor.isClient && Template.registerHelper('TabularTables', TabularTables);

TabularTables.Dealers = new Tabular.Table({
  name: "Dealers",
  collection: Dealers,
  columns:[
     {data: "name", title: "Name"},
     {data: "p_iva", title: "Partita IVA"},
  ]
}, { 
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe("reportPage"),
        ]
    },
    path: "/reportPage"
});
```

> 3. reportpage.html

```
<template name="reportpage">
    {{> tabular table=TabularTables.Dealers class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"}}
</template>
```

How can I fix it?
Please help me! :(

Comment: I'm not much aware of CoffeeScript but .find accepts JSON object. So, In publish method, Dealers.find({'owner': userId}). 
Otherwise, It looks like your HTML get render before data get subscribed, try to subscribe data on the route or Before rendering table check data subscribed or not.

Comment: I tried to apply this

Meteor.publish "reportpage", ->
Dealers.find {
owner: this.userId
}, 

But the data of all users always appears :(

In my case it is only necessary to display the entered data of logged in users (owner)

Comment: Remove autopublish package from your application.

Comment: Already removed, but not working :(

Comment: I found this to be my case, but I can't figure out where to put this:

{userId: Meteor.userId ()}

Look here: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular/issues/13

"And you'll pass {userId: Meteor.userId()} as the selector attribute on the table."

Comment: There is a problem in your data subscription. Because complete data should not be available on client side. Only required information should be available. Are you sure, you are subscribing data on server side. Check the mapping of your collection and also check the data type of the value of owner. Try to execute the same query in Robo Mongo(Database IDE https://robomongo.org/) then you'll get to know the exact result of your query.

Comment: The value of the owner is a "String" (example: "owner": "ixZSawmfmWBM3dTKb"), but I do not think this is the problem, because other users had the same problem and @aldeed proposed a solution using `selector`, but I can't get it running, all user data is displayed.

Comment: The selector is client side so on the client side only data of particular user should be available means there is an error in data publishment. @mOsCpU0 try to fire the same query in Robo Mongo. Then you will get the exact result of your query or  Debug your server code

Comment: Explain me how to do it? with Robomongo?

Comment: Install it from https://robomongo.org/ and start your application locally then follow steps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336163/how-to-connect-robomongo-to-mongodb

Comment: This already does :) talk about how to launch the Query?

Comment: when you double click the collection, you will get the list of documents and on the top of the tab you will find db.getCollection('XXXXXXX').find({}). Update your query and press enter.

Comment: Here is what comes out in this query `db.getCollection('dealers').find({})`, all the Dealers entered, with their ID and each owner

Comment: try this db.getCollection('XXXXXXX').find({ "owner": "ixZSawmfmWBM3dTKb"})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this way:

```
Template.reportpage.helpers({
  selector () {
    if (!!Meteor.userId()) {
      return { owner: Meteor.userId() };
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `selector` to filter results used by tabular.

```
TabularTables.Dealers = new Tabular.Table({
  name: "Dealers",
  collection: Dealers,
  columns:[
    {data: "name", title: "Name"},
    {data: "p_iva", title: "Partita IVA"},
  ], 
  selector: function (userId) {
    if (!!userId) {
      return {owner: userId}
    }
  },
}
```

For more information refer to [Displaying Only Part of a Collection's Data Set](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular#displaying-only-part-of-a-collections-data-set).

Comment: I tried this but it does not work correctly I see a "warning" in Browser Logs and other values appear in the table, including only the owner userId.
I use Documentation: `selector(userId) {
      return {owner: userId}
    }
});`
I then read the documentation, I had already applied it, but it does not work, it returns all the data from all users in the table, the solution proposed by @aldeed in issue #13 would solve the problem using `selector` but i do not know how to apply it

Comment: Sorry, I tried your solution, I missed `}, 'how is it missing in your solution, because I guess the code was not executed correctly, however, all user data is displayed :(